# How to use IQuerable.Select in my own class

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I'm trying to encapsulate an IQuerable in my own generic class and then perform a Select() on this via my own Select() method, but I cannot get it working...

I have this: (Not real working code yet)

```
public class PagedSpQuery<T>
    {
        private IQueryable<T> q = null;

        public PagedSpQuery(MyContext DB)
        {
            q = DB.MyEntity.SqlQuery("select * from MyTable").AsQuerable();
        }

        public IQueryable<T> Select<T>( Expression<Func<T, T>> selector)
        {
          return  q.Select(selector);    
        }
    }
```

I get an error on `q.Select(selector);`

It will not accept the parameter..

I can follow this problem some of the way, but I cannot grasp how to get this to work, if it is possible anyway..

Any ideas would be appreciated..

Thanks..

Comment: IQueryable *is* generic just like IEnumerable<T> or LINQ, it isn't tied to Entity Framework. In fact, it's meant to *encapsulate* queryable providers. Why do you think you need to encapsulate it yourself, especially since you'll end up using the same syntax?

Comment: What's the point of a selector that returns the same type? Are you mutating the inputs or creating _new_ objects based on the input collection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've define the *class* as generic, then defined a generic function that re-uses the type argument `T`, which confuses the conpiler.  There's no reason to add a generic argument to the function, so just take it off:

```
public IQueryable<T> Select(Expression<Func<T, T>> selector)
{
    return  q.Select(selector);    
}
```

But why are you wrapping Linq methods at all?  Why not just have the class implement `IQueryable<T>` and use Linq's implementations?

Comment: Wow that definitively did the trick...  :) I'm not that experienced with generics

Comment: @Beaker Well the code in the question won't even compile, even with this change, so apparently it's not representative of your actual code.

Comment: @Servy what error are you getting?  It compiles for me after the change.

Comment: Actually it is because I want to get my hands on a return parameter after the Query is executed but before the Context is closed. Will try with the IQuerable<T> implementation, but I'm not sure it will work.

Comment: @DStanley The assignment in the constructor is invalid as the type being assigned isn't an `IQueryable<T>`.

Comment: The code was just an example. Will possibly not compile. It was just to show the point of the problem..

Comment: @Servy good catch. I had commented out the constructor since I didn't have the `MyContext` type.